# Is it possible to get an object if exist by object manager in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager

I wanna get some object in magento to like

```
 $this->objectmanager->create(`'path\to\some\class\in\another\module'`)
```

but i wanna get `'path\to\some\class\in\another\module'` object just if the module of this class exist(and get null if not exist instead of php errors). 
is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you do it **programmatically** you can use `class_exists` if you want to check:

```
if (class_exists(path\to\some\class\in\module2::class)) {
    $this->objectmanager->create('path\to\some\class\in\module2');
} else {
    $this->objectmanager->create('path\to\some\class\in\module1');
}
```

Or you can simply **setup a preference in your second module** for the first class in your `di.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="path\to\some\class\in\module1" type="path\to\some\class\in\module2" />
</config>
```

Comment: class_exists seems to be the best way to go.

Comment: yes what a simple way , I did't realise that . thank u

Comment: @aligh feel free to mark the question as answered so it'll benefit for others